# Show or hide a div depending on a radiobutton (checked/not)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After a long time here and using all your information and comments, I was able to solve all of my code problems. Actually, I don't speak too much English. Sorry for that. Anyway, here we go!

I'm doing business practices and they gave me a project and I've almost finished it, but I cannot deal with it:

I have to detect the OS user system by JS and then after that, if the client is using Windows, I should advise him that he can install a ".exe" to run this app via desktop displaying just a `div` within a description (here is the `div` — just a rectangle in this case, so, it doesn't matter). After trying for all of this afternoon, I couldn't solve it and I decided to still testing in at home:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>radio button test [FAILED haha]</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            systemName = navigator.platform;
            if(systemName.indexOf('Win') != -1){
                document.getElementById("good").checked = true;

            }else{document.getElementById("bad").checked = true;}
        });


        if($(#good).is(":checked")){
                $(#ident).style.display = "block";
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <div id="ident"></div>
    <form action="">
        <input type="radio" name="system" id="good" value="good">Windows<br>
        <input type="radio" name="system" id="bad" value="bad">others
    </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

- The problem: I tried to use jQuery to use the Change event on `input#windows`. The problem is, if it's the default option, the `div` won't appear, and, if i try it inside out.

I'm done T.T
In advance, thanks.

PS: it's my first post, so if I did something wrong, sorry!

Comment: You should (1) listen to the `change` event on the radio buttons, and then decide what to do based on the checked/unchecked status and (2) move this event listener into your DOM ready event.

Comment: Make sure you have quotes around your jquery selectors.  e.g. use $('#ident') instead of $(#ident)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not listening to the `change`event. You will have to do that, and when the `change` event is fired, decide what to do based on the checked/unchecked status of the radio buttons. Also, since you mention that listening to `change` event doesn't do anything to the radio buttons on page load, that is because you are not evaluating the checked/unchecked status on page load.

p/s: And you forgot to wrap your selector in quotes.

Therefore, the solution is to fire a function on both page load (or DOM ready) **and** upon change:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var systemName = navigator.platform;
  if (systemName.indexOf('Win') != -1) {
    $('#good').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('#bad').prop('checked', true);
  }

  var updateIdent = function() {
    if ($('#good').is(":checked")) {
      $('#ident').show();
    } else {
      $('#ident').hide();
    }
  }

  // Update when change event is fired
  $('form input[type="radio"]').on('change', updateIdent);

  // Update upon DOM ready
  updateIdent();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ident">IDENT</div>
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="system" id="good" value="good">Windows
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="system" id="bad" value="bad">others
</form>
```

Comment: This solution will work, but if the goal is only to display a div, the radio buttons are an extra step and are not necessary.

Comment: @AdamKonieska Well if OP wants to allow the users to choose themselves (remember that user agents can be spoofed easily), then you should listen to the change event as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is fine, you're just missing some quotes in your jquery and having problems setting the display: block;  This JS will fix it:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        systemName = navigator.platform;
        if(systemName.indexOf('Win') != -1){
            document.getElementById("good").checked = true;
        }else{
            $document.getElementById("bad").checked = true;
        }
    });

    if($('#good').is(":checked")){            
            $('#ident').css('display','block');
    };
```

However, unless you specifically need the radio buttons, you can do without them entirely.  Some JS like this will work best:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        systemName = navigator.platform;
        if(systemName.indexOf('Win') != -1){
            $('#ident').css('display','block');
        }else{
            $('#ident').css('display','none');
        }
    });
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.radioBtn').change(function () {
    if (this.value == 'good') {
        $('#ident').show();
    } else if (this.value == 'bad') {
        $('#ident').hide();
    }
});

systemName = navigator.platform;

if (systemName.indexOf('Win') > -1) {
    $('#good').prop("checked", true).change();

} else {
    $("#bad").prop("checked", true).change();
}
```

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/fmotankv/24/

Also, note that my Fiddle uses CSS to automatically hide the `#ident` div. I would recommend this method to avoid non-Windows users from potentially seeing the div flash on their screen before being removed by the code.